# Python3.6 error when we are passing csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

While reading csv file in python3.6 this error throws:

```
KeyError: 'result'
    Error in sys.excepthook:
       import apt
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
        import apt_pkg
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
    Original exception was:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 117, in <module>
        extractPreservationDataAndSet(l.getPreservationData(), test_response);
      File "main.py", line 21, in extractPreservationDataAndSet
        result = temp_http_response[i];
    KeyError: 'result'
```

How can we solve it ?

Comment: You can't expect us to be able to help you if you don't have any code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

indicates you don't have the apt_pkg module installed. Have a look at the [home page of that package](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt_pkg.html). There is a link on how to install it using the package manager.

The easiest way to install the module is probably:

```
pip3 install python-apt
```

Comment: If this was of use to you, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. It will help others to find it.

Answer (score 0):

This solved mine issue:

```
python3 -c "import nltk; nltk.download('all')"
```

it downloaded and unzipped all the packages.